# PROLOG - Syntax error: Operator expected when using not (..)

Tags: prolog

I'm want to write prolog code to give me L3 that's contains L1 with out the parameters of L2 
 (L3 = L1\L2).

and in this code i got this problem :

Syntax error: Operator expected

for the last line of

```
contains(_,[]) .
contains(L1,[X|TL]) :- member( X, L1) , contains(L1,TL).
minus(L1,L2,L3) :- contains(L3,L1) , not ( contains(L3,L2) ).
```

thanks.

Comment: You should use `\+` instead, as it is a lot more portable. Which implementation of Prolog are you using?

Answer (score 3):

`not` is (usually) not defined as an operator. You should write instead `not( contains(L3,L2) )` or, better yet, use the ISO Prolog standard `(\+)/1` negation control construct and write `\+ ( contains(L3,L2) )`.